# Association with Searchlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchlogic

Hi I have a post model that :has_many :reply, when using searchlogic, doing Post.reply_content_like("search"), returns a result for every reply under that post, I only want it to return once. Anyone know a way to solve this

Comment: One way I could solve this is by deleting duplicate entries in the array of hashes that is produced from querying the model. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searchlogic returns an array of Posts matching your criteria, just as if you used an ActiveRecord `find`. If you only want to get one result, well, which one? The first? The last?

If you want to get the unique, matched column values, you could do

`Post.reply_content_like("search").collect(&:reply_content).uniq`

or if you just want the first Post

`Post.reply_content_like("search").first`